# jquery add/remove multiple inputs from multiple selects (dropdowns)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, show-hide

I have many selects in a form.

I want to add to a few selects in a form an option "Other". When "Other" is selected it shows a hidden input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".SelectOther").append('<option value=-1>Other</option>');
$(".OtherDiv").hide();
    $(".SelectOther").change(function()
    {
        if($(".SelectOther option:selected").text() == "Other")
        {
            $(".OtherDiv").show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            $(".OtherDiv").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        }
    });

});
```

Didn't test this code yet, but this would open all hidden "OtherDiv"s

All selects are within a TD within a table.

How can a make sure When selecting "Other" it only shows the hidden input within that TD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :**

Use `$(this)`. By this way you'll know you're in the correct context.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".SelectOther").append('<option value=-1>Other</option>');
   $(".OtherDiv").hide();
   $(".SelectOther").change(function() {
     var otherDiv =  $(this).closest("tr").find(".OtherDiv"); // find the .otherdiv within the tr
     if($(this).find("option:selected").text() == "Other") //find the selected option
     {
           otherDiv.show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
     }
     else
     {
           otherDiv.hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
     }
    });

});
```

**EDIT:**

To add or remove a class, you can use `toggleClass("classname")`, or `addClass("classname")`/ `removeClass("classname")`.

**More info about the stuff used here :**

**`$(this)`**

- Docs : http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/
- What it does : Returns the current context.

**`find()`**

- Docs : http://api.jquery.com/find/
- What it does : Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Comment: do you know how I can add and remove the "required" class to them when they show?

Comment: To add or remove a class, you can use toggleClass("classname"), or addClass("classname")/ removeClass("classname").